# Code not working, could not find function. Maps package

Tags: r, maps

This error has me completely stumped. This morning my code worked, this afternoon it does not.

I'm using the maps package to bring through the country code based on Longitude and Latitude coordinates within a data frame. The code I am using is: `Latest[, COUNTRY := map.where(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)]`

This morning this worked fine, but now, this afternoon, I get the following error message:

> Error in `:=`(COUNTRY, map.where(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)) :
> could not find function ":="

I had installed other map packages in a desperate bid to try and identify cases that retrieved an NA result using this code, that's the only change I made.

Since then I have:

Restarted RStudio

Restarted my computer

Deleted all new packages and restarted Rstudo

Deleted and reinstalled R itself including packages

Deleted RStudio and reinstalled with the same version

Restarted my computer again

No matter what I do it just resolutely gives the same meaningless, at least to me, error.

I'm getting desperate here folks, have a major project I need to get over the line and this error has ground me to a halt!

Comment: That is `data.table` syntax - it has nothing to to do with `Maps` package. Make sure you have loaded `library(data.table)` and that `Latest` is of class `data.table`.

Comment: Or switch to `base` syntax: `Latest$Country = map.where(x = Latest$Longitude, y = Latest$Latitude))`. Or use `dplyr`: `library(dplyr); Latest = Latest %>% mutate(Country = map.where(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))`

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas I deleted data.table and reinstalled it (because it was being loaded as a library) and progress has moved on a bit as it now generates a new error:

Error in `:=`(COUNTRY, map.where(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

But your dplyr solution seems happy and has worked. I just can't understand why my original code worked this morning and is now giving errors even though the data frame load and structure is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas Although I do not understand why it is not working on the orignial method the dplyr solution works and I can get this project out of the door. Was pulling my hair out!

Comment: The new error means you have `data.table` loaded as it should be, so the `:=` command is recognized. But you ignored the second half of my comment "*Make sure ... `Latest` is of class `data.table`*". The operator is recognized but it still only works on data tables. You could use `Latest = as.data.table(Latest)` or more simply `setDT(Latest)` to make it a data.table and your code would probably work.

Comment: As for why things changed, you probably entered `library(data.table)` and `setDT(Latest)` in the console rather than saving it in a script this morning. There's no other likely explanation.

Comment: @GregorThomas I'm still quite new to R, I had to just google what setDT meant (assumed setDataTable) so definitely did not use it.

The data frame in question is created using the readRDS command.

Comment: Okay, so maybe you used `as.data.table` not `setDT` this morning - they do the same thing. It doesn't matter. Somehow, this morning, you attached the data.table package and converted `Latest` to class `data.table`, but whatever code you used to do that got lost.